# Script not working as expected when transposed to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have written java script to validate signup information but it is not working when i joined it to action.php file.but it works fine in html file.
it also dosen't work after refreshing of the page.i am not getting what is wrong with it.please do help  to solve this problem.

it is signup page.

```
<?php include 'conn.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
</head>
   <body onload="form.reset();"">
    <div class="container">
       <div id="grad">
            <ul>
          <li style=""><a href="#contact">Helping Hands...</a></li>
          <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about"> Have an account? Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>   
       <form name=form action="#" onsubmit="return validate()" autocomplete=on method="post">   
        <div class="outsidebox" >
          <div class='login'>
              <h2>Register</h2>
              <div class="agree1">
                 <label style="margin-left: 30px;"> <input id="ngo" type="radio" name="option" value="ngo" checked>NGO</label>
                 <label style="margin-left:30px;"><input id="ind" type="radio" name="option" value="ind">INDIVIDUAL</label>
              </div>
             <span><input name='uname' placeholder='Username' type='text' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; $_SESSION['name']='';?>'>
               <p id="username" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p>
             </span>
             <span><input name='email' placeholder='E-Mail Address' type='text'>

               <p id="email" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
             <span> <input name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password'>
              <p id="password" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
              <span><input name='passwordcon' placeholder=' Confirm Password' type='password'>
               <p id="passwordcon" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
              <span><input name='fullname' placeholder='Enter Your Full Name ' type='text'>
               <p id="fullname" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
              <div id="a1" >
                    <strong>PLEASE SELECT FIELDS</strong><br>
                    <div class="fields">
                     <select name="fields" id="fields">
                                <option value="child">Child Welfare</option>
                        <option value="education">Child Education</option>
                        <option value="relief">Disaster Management and relief</option>
                        <option value="envir">Environment</option>
                        <option value="animals">Animals</option>
                     </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              <div class='agree'>
                <input id='agree' name='agree' type='checkbox'>
                <label for='agree'></label>Accept rules and conditions
              </div>
              <input class='animated' type='submit' value='Register'>
              <a class='forgot' href='#'>Already have an account?</a>


        </div>         
        </div>
        </form>
   </body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ngo").click(function(){
        $("#a1").show();
    });
    $("#ind").click(function(){
        $("#a1").hide();
    });
});
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function validate(){
  var flag=1;
   var form=document.forms.form;
   var user=form.username.value;

       if(user==null || user==""){
        user="please enter username";
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML=user;
        flag=0;
       }
       else{
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML="";
       }
      var email=form.email.value; 
     if(email==null ||email==""){
        email="please enter email";
        document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=email;

        flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML="";
       }
     var password=form.password.value;
     if(password==null || password==""){
            password="please enter password";
            document.getElementById("password").innerHTML=password;
            flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("password").innerHTML="";
       }
     var passwordcon=form.passwordcon.value;
     if(passwordcon==null || passwordcon==""){
        passwordcon="please conform password";
        document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML=passwordcon;
        flag=0;
     }
        else{
            document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML="";
            }
     if(passwordcon!=password){
        passwordcon =" pasword confirmation fail";
        document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML=passwordcon;
        flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML="";
       }
     var fullname=form.fullname.value;
     if (fullname==null || fullname=="") {
        fullname="Enter full name";
        document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML=fullname;
        flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML="";
       }
     if(flag==0){
        return false;
     }
     else{
        return true;
`enter code here`     }
}
</script>

</html>
```

it is my action.php as inputs.php in which i have written defined    session variables.to send error to signup page;and also i am performing 
email validation check.Then i check username is used or not to insert this
into the database.

.

```
<?php include 'conn.php'; ?>
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    {
            $password=$_POST["password"];
            $fullname=$_POST["fullname"];
            $uname=$_POST["uname"];
            $ngo=$_POST["option"];
            $field=$_POST["field"];
            $email=$_POST["email"];
            $_SESSION['uerr']='';
            $_SESSION['emailerr']='';

         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true){
                    $emailerr="Inavalid Email";
                $_SESSION['email']=$emailerr;
                $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname='$uname' LIMIT 1";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                 $countu= mysqli_num_rows($result);
                 echo "in emailerr".$countu; 
                 if($countu==0)
                 {
                       $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname;
                       $_SESSION['field']=$field;
                       $_SESSION['name']=$uname;
                       $_SESSION['emailerr']=$emailerr;
                       $_SESSION['email']='';
                       die(header('Location:signup2.php'));

                 }
                 else{
                       $uerr="USER NAME already taken";
                       $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname;
                       $_SESSION['field']=$field;
                       $_SESSION['name']='';
                       $_SESSION['uerr']=$uerr;
                       $_SESSION['emailerr']=$emailerr;
                       $_SESSION['email']='';
                      echo "in esle";
                      die(header('Location:signup2 .php'));
                 }
            }
             /* $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname='$uname' LIMIT 1";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                 $countu= mysqli_num_rows($result);
                  $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
                  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                  $counte = mysqli_num_rows($result);
               if($counte==1 && $countu==1)
               {
                       $uerr="USER NAME already taken";
                       $emailerr="email already taken";
                       $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname;
                       $_SESSION['field']=$field;
                       $_SESSION['emailerr']=$emailerr;
                       $_SESSION['uerr']=$uerr;
                        echo "in bothlerr"; 
                       die(header('Location:signup1.php'));


                }
                elseif($counte==1)
               {

                       $emailerr="email already taken";
                       $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname;
                       $_SESSION['field']=$field;
                       $_SESSION['name']=$uname;
                       $_SESSION['emailerr']=$emailerr;
                       $_SESSION['email']='';
                        echo "in boeerr"; 
                        die(header('Location:signup1.php'));
                } 
                 elseif($countu==1)
               {
                       $uerr="USER NAME already taken";
                      $_SESSION['fullname']=$fullname;
                       $_SESSION['field']=$field;
                       $_SESSION['email']=$email;
                        $_SESSION['uerr']=$uerr;
                        $_SESSION['name']='';
                         echo "in uerr"; 
                        die(header('Location:signup1.php'));
                }


            else{
                 if($ngo="ngo"){ 
                 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
                 $date=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
                 $sql="INSERT INTO user(uname,email,password,dtime,full_name,field) VALUES ( '$uname', '$email', '$password','$date','$fullname','$field')";
                 mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                 echo "in ngo data inserted";
                }
                else{
                        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
                        $date=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
                        $field='none';
                        $sql="INSERT INTO user(uname,email,password,dtime,full_name,field) VALUES ( '$uname', '$email', '$password','$date','$fullname','$field')";
                        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        echo "in ind datainserted";
                    }




         }*/
    }

?>
```

and last one is main signup.html file in which javascript works well.
i want to perform some error checking that is why i have saved it as 
signup2.php in htdocs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
</head>
   <body onload="form.reset();"">
    <div class="container">
       <div id="grad">
            <ul>
          <li style=""><a href="#contact">Helping Hands...</a></li>
          <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about"> Have an account? Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>   
       <form name=form action="#" onsubmit="return validate()" autocomplete=on method="post">   
        <div class="outsidebox" >
          <div class='login'>
              <h2>Register</h2>
              <div class="agree1">
                 <label style="margin-left: 30px;"> <input id="ngo" type="radio" name="option" value="ngo" checked>NGO</label>
                 <label style="margin-left:30px;"><input id="ind" type="radio" name="option" value="ind">INDIVIDUAL</label>
              </div>
             <span><input name='username' placeholder='Username' type='text'>
               <p id="username" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p>
             </span>
             <span><input name='email' placeholder='E-Mail Address' type='text'>

               <p id="email" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
             <span> <input name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password'>
              <p id="password" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
              <span><input name='passwordcon' placeholder=' Confirm Password' type='password'>
               <p id="passwordcon" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
              <span><input name='fullname' placeholder='Enter Your Full Name ' type='text'>
               <p id="fullname" style="font-size: 12px;color:red;"></p></span>
              <div id="a1" >
                    <strong>PLEASE SELECT FIELDS</strong><br>
                    <div class="fields">
                     <select name="fields" id="fields">
                                <option value="child">Child Welfare</option>
                        <option value="education">Child Education</option>
                        <option value="relief">Disaster Management and relief</option>
                        <option value="envir">Environment</option>
                        <option value="animals">Animals</option>
                     </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              <div class='agree'>
                <input id='agree' name='agree' type='checkbox'>
                <label for='agree'></label>Accept rules and conditions
              </div>
              <input class='animated' type='submit' value='Register'>
              <a class='forgot' href='#'>Already have an account?</a>


        </div>         
        </div>
        </form>
   </body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ngo").click(function(){
        $("#a1").show();
    });
    $("#ind").click(function(){
        $("#a1").hide();
    });
});
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function validate(){
  var flag=1;
   var form=document.forms.form;
   var user=form.username.value;

       if(user==null || user==""){
        user="please enter username";
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML=user;
        flag=0;
       }
       else{
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML="";
       }
      var email=form.email.value; 
     if(email==null ||email==""){
        email="please enter email";
        document.getElementById("email").innerHTML=email;

        flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML="";
       }
     var password=form.password.value;
     if(password==null || password==""){
            password="please enter password";
            document.getElementById("password").innerHTML=password;
            flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("password").innerHTML="";
       }
     var passwordcon=form.passwordcon.value;
     if(passwordcon==null || passwordcon==""){
        passwordcon="please conform password";
        document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML=passwordcon;
        flag=0;
     }
        else{
            document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML="";
            }
     if(passwordcon!=password){
        passwordcon =" pasword confirmation fail";
        document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML=passwordcon;
        flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("passwordcon").innerHTML="";
       }
     var fullname=form.fullname.value;
     if (fullname==null || fullname=="") {
        fullname="Enter full name";
        document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML=fullname;
        flag=0;
     }
      else{
            document.getElementById("fullname").innerHTML="";
       }
     if(flag==0){
        return false;
     }
     else{
        return true;
     }
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: you should debug your code

Comment: Have you ever realized your signup page has an html error.
 <body onload="form.reset();""> two double quotes.

Comment: Long code listings to then simply ask "whats wrong", will not help you easily getting the answer you need.

Comment: thank you all for your kind suggestion. Yeah solved the error.it was in java script.user=form.username.value;it should have been user=form.uname.value; because i have used name to intupt user block as name=uname.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up your code and format your HTML properly before proceeding with troubleshooting should you still not be able to achieve your intended purpose after this exercise.

As pointed out in comments below your initial post, you code contains lots of problems and need to be well formed;

- Your **`</head>`** element *should have* a **`<title>`** instance.
- You should have **`<body onload="form.reset();">`** *(without the extra double quotes at the end, after the semi-column)*.
- Remember to close your **`<div class="container">`**; it's currently not.
- Your **`<p>`** elements *should not* be child elements of **`<span>`** as this is actually not allowed according to your declared document type definition, *`<!DOCTYPE html>`*.
  *... more details [here, for **`<p>`**](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-p-element)*, and [*here, for **`<span>`***](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-span-element).
- Close your **`<body>`** tag right before your **`</html>`**; not after **`</form>`**.
  Your JavaScript contents are still part of your page content and as such *should be* within the opened and closed `body` tag if not declared in your `head` section.

Feel free to omit the *`language="javascript"`* attribute on your **`<script>`** element; it's obsolete.